Which raytracing program are included in Ubuntu Studio?
I was familiar with povray for Windows long time ago. Which kind of raytracing is possible with Ubuntu?

Wrong place to ask this. Software recommends are off topic.

@DavidDE That's new to me, when did that change?

As long as I have used this site. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic Has been the bible of what you can and should not ask.

@DavidDE Seems you mean hardware recommendations which are indeed off-topic. Software recommendations are of course on-topic.

It says both are off topic and many questions have been removed for this, not my idea site policy. Talk to the Mods.

From the link in the doc. In fact SR (which is a site dedicated to the topic) has guidance for asking for alternatives and how to ask for useful and specific software recommendations. This rules can be applied to HW/shopping recommendations, yes, but then, most of users doesn't know how to ask properly and reshaping the question is sometimes outside our possibilities.

@DavidDE https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14394/are-software-recommendations-on-topic-or-not

Some improvements to your question:
"povray" -is- avail for Ubuntu per answer. You should edit your question so it reads:
"What types of raytracing software are available for Ubuntu?"
add tag 'software-recommendation'

sorry for rise this

@SteffenGollmer If my answer below was helpful, please accept the answer, thanks.

A software is either included or not included. I don't understand what you mean with "deeper included". As far as I know, Ubuntu Studio doesn't include any raytracing program.
However, povray is available from the ubuntu repositories (universe) for all supported versions of Ubuntu as you can see here.
You can install povray in any flavour of Ubuntu with
sudo apt update
sudo apt install povray

